# iterating over sys.argv[] (python)

Tags: python

I was trying to read several files from a command line argument using this iterating code, but i get a Type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Can someone help me fix this

code:

```
for x in sys.argv[1::]
    fileobj = open(sys.argv[x], 'r')
    #read file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`: This means you are using a str for a list index. Where are you accessing a list index? It's at `sys.argv[x]`. So it's complaining that `x` is a `str` instead of an `int`.

That is because when you say `for x in sys.argv[1::]`, `x` is the actual content of the list, which in this case are the actual file names. So you either need to say:

```
for x in sys.argv[1::]
    fileobj = open(x, 'r')
```

or

```
for x in range(1, len(sys.argv))
    fileobj = open(sys.argv[x], 'r')
```

The first one is considered more readable by most.